# Multiple questions related to Flutter basic

Tags: flutter, dart

I am coming from React and trying to understand Flutter. There are some differences between dart vs JS and React vs Flutter. However, it seems a bit similar to each other. However, there is some confusion toward Flutter.

1. `void`

It does not return the value. Therefore, it is used to `void main()`. Does it mean like the function 'main()' will be executed and I will never be able to reuse `void main()`?

2. `<>`

In the code, I have here

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return new LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  Widget build(context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            emailField(),
            // passwordField(),
            // submitButton(),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I can see that `State<LoginScreen>` is related to `class LoginScreen`. It is an extension of the `LoginScreen` State?

```
Future<int> successor = future.then((int value) {
  
  },
```

However, in here Future <----- I do not understand why it has to state 'int' in this code. What is the proper use of `<>`?

3. Stateful vs Stateless

Can I just use the `Stateful` all the time even if I do not have any state like React? Where there is no difference?

Comment: That `main()` returns `void` has nothing to do with it being reusable or not.  It's called for its side-effect, just like other functions that return`void` (e.g. `print`).  Normally you wouldn't want or need to call `main()` again, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn basic dart.

1. `void main()` is same as `main()`. The only difference is declaring the return type. `main()` is called only once by the flutter engine.
2. Read about generics. `<>` is the called the diamond operator and is used to specify the type of something. `Future<int>` means the function will return something in future and it will strictly be of `int` type. If you don't specify the type flutter will treat it as `dynamic`.
3. You can use `stateful` classes if you are using state management packages like `provider` or `rxdart` to maintain state.

Comment: It is more close to TypeScript, as I see. I am also studying Dart as well. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: `main()` is called *automatically* once, but it's still a function; it can be called multiple times like any other function.  For example, `main()` could be recursive.

Answer (score 1):

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return new LoginScreenState();
  }
}

    enter code here

changed to 
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreenState createState()=>LoginScreenState();
  }
}

    enter code here

Stateful vs Stateless`enter code here`
stateful has state object and stateless has no state object.using stateful you can changes widget data .on other hand in stateful you cant
```